# Grep extract substring starting with specific pattern

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu

I am  extracting a list of issues different from one commit til the next with 
git log --oneline  25757d1b890...6ec5a49418e
This gives the full commit message and branch like:

```
(origin/SWEB-415_search-results-hover-actions) Merge branch 'staging' into SWEB-415_search-results-hover-actions
```

How could I extract SWEB-414 from this line in a grep?

Comment: But this line has `SWEB-415`

Answer (score 0):

`grep` only deals with lines. To extract part of a line, you'd need to pipe to another tool, like `sed`. How exactly your sed command would look depends on what pattern you expect from your output.